# Keep a rug lying flat on a carpet

Tags: adhesive, carpet

I've got a large rug (7 feet by 5 feet, or 2.1 metre by 1.5 metre) in my living room with a coffee table on top (see image below). As you can see, the rug keeps curling, particularly around the coffee table.

[image]

I've searched the web and all results tend to focus on keeping a rug flat when placed on a hard floor (such as tile or wood). But what about when it's rug on carpet?

I have tried duct tape, and that worked alright (until the adhesive wore off), but now I have goo left where the tape used to be.

[image]

Any way to keep it lying flat without ruining my carpet with duct tape?

Comment: Welcome to Lifehacks S.E.! If you need any additional assistance, please visit [The Help Center](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to get some heavy-duty red thread and sew the edges of the rug to your carpet. (I'm not sure; I haven't tried it.) Removing the rug would be as simple as cutting a few of the heavy-duty threads.

Comment: That may be the way to do it. Thanks for the response.

Comment: You're welcome! If it works, please click the check mark next to my answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could pin the rug through the carpet into the floor. Use nails with wide heads, or a heavy duty staple gun. A couple on each end of the rug should hold it steady. Another option, as stated in another answer would be to see the rug to the carpet. 
You can also get a rubber mat to hold it still, although designed for hard floor I think it would be effective, but not as much as the previous options and also more costly than the previous suggestions.